# Correct wait to wait for a given Database Value using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Currently I have created DB logic which will execute a given command against a target database in order to retrieve specific data.

Currently trying to figure out the correct way to wait for a given value to be present within the database before proceeding with the next database command.

Please could you give your thoughts on the below logic?

```
createDatabaseConnection(); //will create the DB connection

//Will execute a given DB query
public static void executeSqlUpdateStatement(String query) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch(MySQLTransactionRollbackException ex) {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to execute method executeSqlUpdateStatement, Exception: " + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}

//Example DB Query
while(!DbManager.executeSingleStatementSqlQueryExtractBasedOnColumn(Booking_Scripts.verifyStatusOfMostRecentBooking("212sdsgge23dds6847"), 1).equals("COMPLETED")) {
      //run a command until while equals true (COMPLETED)
}
```

closeDatabaseConnection(); //will close the DB connection

As you can see from the above code, only until the specific SQL data equals 'COMPLETED' will it break the loop, happy the hear your thoughts on the above logic?

Comment: What changes that value to 'COMPLETED'? A different thread or another app?

Comment: First of, are you declaring `executeSqlUpdateStatement` inside of some other method? Or are you calling `createDatabaseConnection` outside of any method? Do you want to execute that checking method after closing the connection? How would that work? Other than that you need some kind of a wait between queries, your current solution would constantly check it.

Comment: what do you mean by "wait for a given value to be present within the database"?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, an external app changes the status to 'COMPLETED', all methods will be executed inside the createDatabaseConnection and closeDatabaseConnection statements. For example the while logic will poll the Database for a given record checking to see whether the status is equal to COMPLETED, if it does not equal COMPLETED then another SQL statement will be triggered which will conduct other measures (Which have not been added to the ticket to avoid bloating this stackoverflow question).

Comment: @Lalit Mehra if the specific cell which executeSingleStatementSqlQueryExtractBasedOnColumn is checking does not equal to completed, then the while loop will continue to poll the db, for example if after 30seconds the value changes to completed then the code will jump out of the while loop.

Comment: @Gbru a better way to do this would be using the event driver approach where every next query/statement would be called once the earlier statement is COMPLETED rather that using a while loop